# PHP if statement stops remainder of HTML page from loading

Tags: php, mysql

The following if statement does not seem to be working for me.

The two values in b1rafrica and b2rafrica are BIGINTs being pulled from a MySQL database (perhaps that might be something to do with it?).

When I run it with these values the site doesn't load:

b1rafrica = 200
b2rafrica = 150

If I remove the else then the site works...

I'm a total PHP noob so I apologise in advance if i'm doing something very stupid.

```html
if ($b1rafrica >= $b2rafrica) {
    $africastyle ="africab1";
   }
  } else {
   $africastyle ="africab2";
  }
```

Cheers,

Will

Comment: If you enable error reporting to the highest level and you enable display errors as well as logging errors to file, PHP will immediately tell you where an error occurred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please provice more info, like what errors you're getting. But try this:

```
if ($b1rafrica >= $b2rafrica) {
    $africastyle ="africab1";
} else {
    $africastyle ="africab2";
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Silly } ruining my day. Thanks a lot!